# How to sort checked checkboxes to the top using Jquery Sortable?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using Jquery Sortable to allow user to sort a few table rows.

What I need to do is when a user checks a checkbox, it will be sorted to the top.

Basically checked items go to the top and unchecked items go to the bottom.

I have included a jfiddle link here to the working code. Anyone up to the challenge ?

http://jsfiddle.net/z74VH/3/

Here is the html:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" id="sort">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>active</td>
        <td>title</td>
        <td>order</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="1">
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="active_1" checked="checked"/></td>
        <td>First Item</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="order_1" value="1"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="active_2" /></td>
        <td>Second Item</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="order_2" value="2"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="active_3" /></td>
        <td>Third Item</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="order_3" value="3"/></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And this is the javascript to call Jquery Sortable:

```
//Call the sortable jquery on the table
$("#sort tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelperModified
}).disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could approach this:

**1: MVVM**

Right now, you have simple DOM objects--a table with multiple rows and columns.

To get this to work correctly, smoothly, and reliably, you need to separate out the data from the representation.  Meaning, you need to create an array of javascript objects to store the data and then a "render" method to create the table dynamically.

Whenever something changes with the data (whether the data is changed from the dragging of the sortable or by the clicking of the checkbox), you will need to re-render the table to show the new sort order.

There are several libraries to help you do this (Backbone, Ember, Knockout, etc)

**2: Ugly Mess**

If you chose to hard-code this, then you'll need to use jQuery to write an ugly algorithm to push that item to the top of the non-checkbox items.

The algorithm will look something like this:

- Find the current parent <tr>

  ```
  var currTR = $(this).closest("tr");
  ```
- In a loop, go to the previous  item that until you find one that has a checkbox in the checked state

  ```
  var prevTR = currTR.prev();
  var insertTR = currTR;
  while(prevTR !== null) {
      if ($(prevTR).find("input:checked").length > 0) {
          break;
      }
      insertTR = currTR;
      prevTR = prevTR.prev();
  }
  ```
- Remove the current <tr> (from the first step)

  ```
  $(currTR).remove();
  ```
- Insert the current <tr> above the last item found from the second step (above the insertTR

Note: This is all pretty much pseudo-code--not at all guaranteed to work!

Also, you'll need to protect yourself in case there are no other items in that are checked or the current row is already the top in the list or top of the unchecked items.

Personally, I'd recommend now as a perfect time to migrate to a javascript framework.

Comment: Actually, the items are already generated dynamically from PHP. Like order1, order2 .. etc.

How would this work in conjunction with a javascript framework AND jquery ?

I have to say, this solution seems intriguing.

Comment: The javascript framework would go in the middle.  On page load, it would pull the data and display it.  Your PHP, instead of generating HTML directly, would generate the data for the front-end.  A link: [Using Knockout.js with PHP](http://www.softfinity.com/blog/using-knockout-js-with-php-best-practices/).  Also, an [Introduction to KnockoutJS](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/).  (I picked KO randomly.  I use Backbone, myself.)  Ultimately, it's about separating the data from the representation.  It makes life 10x easier.